# mod_rewrite on 1and1 hosting is giving me infinite redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Why is the following line resulting in infinite redirects?

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/(.*)$ article.php?anum=$1 [L]
```

If I change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^boo/([^/]+)/(.*)$ article.php?anum=$1 [L]
```

It works fine, so it's something to do with the "article" word but, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong.

The mod_rewrite rule tester [here](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) reports that the rule works fine.  It may also be something to do with the way 1and1 has mod_rewrite set up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be MultiViews - that would deliver `article.php` when just `article` is requested. Try turning it of by using `Options -MultiViews` in your .htaccess.

Comment: That was it.  Brilliant.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be MultiViews - that would deliver `article.php` when just `article` is requested.

Try turning it of by using `Options -MultiViews` in your .htaccess.